# visual studio 2017 community "dotnet.exe exited with code 1"

Tags: crash, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

How do I find out just what error it is having?
OS is windows 10 pro.
This problem seems to be there whether I run console or web service.
for me to reproduce this, I can simply create a new console project, then run it.
windows event logs didn't show anything that seem related.

Comment: Related post - [The program '3984 dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450751 (0x80008081)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48672371/465053)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the way I did it is I ran commandline dotnet consoleapp1.dll and got the error it was having.  Thanks

Comment: You might want to apprise the community as to what was the real error coming when you ran it from command line and how you went past the real error. Your details might help someone down the line.

Comment: I had this issue and the problem was that the project was targeting .NET Core 2.1.3 while I had the 2.1.2 SDK installed